# Replace function with pythons built in map function

Tags: python, lambda

**Problem** : I want to improve my understanding of the python map function. I made a function which can return the lengths of words in a given phrase as a list. However, I would like to simply use the map function with a lambda function and pass in a string. Also, I am using python 3.

**Current Function (WORKS)** :

```
phrase = 'How long are the words in this phrase'

def word_lengths(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.split(' ')
    wordLengthList = []
    for i in range(len(phrase)):
        wordLengthList.append(len(phrase[i]))
    return wordLengthList

word_lengths(phrase)
```

**Current implementation of map (DOES NOT WORK)**:

```
 list(map(lambda x: len(x.split(' ')), phrase))
```

If anyone could help me resolve this issue I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Please update your question to fix the indenting. Python is very sensitive to indenting, as are python programmers.

Comment: Generally speaking, `map` is a little outdated and you might be better off using a list comprehension or a generator expression. Plus personally I find them more readable.

Comment: Are you looking for just `map(len, phrase.split(' '))`? Hard to tell, because your `Current Function (WORKS)` - actually doesn't (`lst` is undefined).

Comment: Why on earth would you even *want* to use `list(map(lambda...` instead of a list comprehension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to split the input parameter for the phrase variable.

```
print(list(map(lambda x: len(x), phrase.split(" "))))
```

**Output:**

```
[3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
```

**From the comments:** better way of doing it. Thanks Lukas Graf.

```
print(list(map(len, phrase.split(" ")))
```

Comment: That `lambda x: len(x)` is completely redundant. -> `map(len, phrase.split(' '))`

Comment: @LukasGraf; You are right. I was just helping the OP's original problem :).

Comment: @LukasGraf and so is the space to `split`; it's the default and can be omitted.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis no, the default is [basically "any whitespace"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split), which includes newlines. Slightly different semantics.

Answer (score 2):

Here are 4 pieces of code for your logic.

I've added the `map` without `lambda` as this is most efficient, and also a list comprehension variety as many consider this most pythonic. Timings are indicative only.

```
phrase = 'How long are the words in this phrase'

def word_lengths(phrase):
    phrase = phrase.split(' ')
    wordLengthList = []
    for i in range(len(phrase)):
        wordLengthList.append(len(phrase[i]))
    return wordLengthList

def word_lengths_map(phrase):
    return list(map(len, phrase.split(' ')))

def word_lengths_lambda(phrase):
    return list(map(lambda x: len(x), phrase.split(' ')))

def word_lengths_lcomp(phrase):
    return [len(x) for x in phrase.split(' ')]

word_lengths(phrase)         # 4.5 microseconds
word_lengths_map(phrase)     # 2.3 microseconds
word_lengths_lambda(phrase)  # 4.0 microseconds
word_lengths_lcomp(phrase)   # 2.8 microseconds
# [3, 4, 3, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

doing this `list(map(lambda x: len(x.split(' ')), phrase))` will make map go through each element of phrase (which is a single character), and it will split each of those 1 characters by ' ' (thus creating arrays of length 1)

you should instead split the entire phrase:

```
list(map(len, phrase.split(' ')))
```

Comment: @StefanPochmann you are right but  there is no point in editing the answer

Answer (score -1):

Use map function as follows:

**list(map(lambda word: len(word),phrase))**

it works perfectly.there is no need to split the word again once we have it.